# Flask Migration integration in sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, database-migration

I am trying to integrate migration in the SQLite database in my Flask app. I have used

```
set FLASK_APP = Basic.py
```

in the terminal of Pycharm of the project directory then run

```
flask db init
```

But it is not working. Here are my codes:

`Basic.py`

```
__author__ = 'User'
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate,MigrateCommand


basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

#__file__ -->Main.py

print(basedir)

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///'+os.path.join(basedir,'data.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATION'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

Migrate(app,db)

####################################################

class Puppy(db.Model):

    #manual table name choice
    __tablename__ = 'puppies'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Puppy {} is {} year/s old".format(self.name, self.age)
```

## setupdatabase.py

```
__author__ = 'Mitu'
from Basic import  db,Puppy

#CREATE ALL THE TABLES Model
db.create_all()


sam = Puppy('Sammy',3)
frank = Puppy('Frankie',4)


#none
#none
print(sam.id)
print(frank.id)

db.session.add_all([sam,frank])

db.session.commit()

print(sam.id)
print(frank.id)
```

## crud.py

```
__author__ = 'Mitu'
from Basic import  db,Puppy

### Create ###

my_puppy = Puppy('Rufus',5)
db.session.add(my_puppy)

db.session.commit()

#### Read ####

all_puppies = Puppy.query.all() #list of all puppies object

print(all_puppies)

# select by id

puppy_one = Puppy.query.get(1)
print(puppy_one)

# filters
# produce some sl code!
puppy_frankie = Puppy.query.filter_by(name='Frankie')
print(puppy_frankie.all())

#["Frankie is 3 years old"]


#### update

first_puppy = Puppy.query.get(1)
first_puppy.age = 10
db.session.add(first_puppy)
db.session.commit()


#### delete

second_pup = Puppy.query.get(2)
db.session.delete(second_pup)
db.session.commit()

# now all puppies

all_puppies = Puppy.query.all()
print(all_puppies)
```

Last two files are for setup the database and for the CRUD operation of sqlite database.

My main problem is migration is not integrating.

Comment: Can you kindly replace both screenshots of Pycharm with formatted error traceback that is shown in the terminal?

Comment: I have updated those screenshots.

Comment: Sorry, I asked to replace screenshots / images with proper formatted code block. You know screenshots are difficult to view. You are trying to load an existing SQLite db to your app? Both the DB and `db.Model` contains same data structure?

Comment: I think both db and db.Model contains same data structure. I have updated my question with rest of the file's codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed the required packages in a virtual environment created using Python 3.5.

```
virtualenv -p python3 venv --no-site-packages
source venv/bin/activate
pip install flask
pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy
pip install Flask-Migrate
pip freeze>requirements.txt
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
alembic==1.0.8
Click==7.0
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Migrate==2.4.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
Mako==1.0.8
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-editor==1.0.4
six==1.12.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.2
Werkzeug==0.15.2
```

As `flask-migrate` searches for `app.py` when running `flask db init`, I renamed `Basic.py` to `app.py`.

I ran attached `setupdatabase.py` to create the SQLite database and `crud.py` to create dummy records.

I created a route to test if these SQLite data are being passed to Flask template.

updated `app.py`:

```
__author__ = 'User'


import os
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand


basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///'+os.path.join(basedir,'data.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATION'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

class Puppy(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'puppies'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Puppy {} is {} year/s old".format(self.name, self.age)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    data = Puppy.query.all()
    return render_template("home.html", data = data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`home.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Puppies</h3>
    <div>{{ data }}</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The data are passed to template:

[image: SQLite data passed to template]

Then I ran the `init`, `migrate` and `upgrade` command as instructed in [official documentation of flask-migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

```
(venv) ➜ flask db init
/home/.../flask_data_migration/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:794: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
  Creating directory
  /home/.../flask_data_migration/migrations ... done
  Creating directory
  /home/.../flask_data_migration/migrations/versions
  ... done
  Generating
  /home/.../flask_data_migration/migrations/env.py ... done
  Generating
  /home/.../flask_data_migration/migrations/README ... done
  Generating /home/.../flask_data_migration/migrations
  /script.py.mako ... done
  Generating /home/.../flask_data_migration/migrations
  /alembic.ini ... done
  Please edit configuration/connection/logging settings in '/home/.../flask_data_migration/migrations/alembic.ini' before proceeding.

(venv) ➜ flask db migrate
/home/.../flask_data_migration/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:794: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.env] No changes in schema detected.

(venv) ➜ flask db upgrade
/home/.../flask_data_migration/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:794: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
```

Directory structure after running the migrations (skipped venv folder):

```
.
├── app.py
├── crud.py
├── data.sqlite
├── migrations
│   ├── alembic.ini
│   ├── env.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── env.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── README
│   ├── script.py.mako
│   └── versions
├── requirements.txt
├── setupdatabase.py
└── templates
    └── home.html
```

Comment: Thanks for running the code. I am confused where should I run 
flask db init   
I tried in the terminal of pycharm, cmd, and anaconda 
where did you run this command line ?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu terminal. I have created a virtual environment and installed all the packages. Rename `Basic.py` to `app.py`. Then check if the required packages are accessible from the terminal (Pycharm / Anaconda) by using `pip freeze` command. If you can see the packages, try `flask db init`, `flask db migrate` and `flask db upgrade` one after another.

Comment: Can I create the virtual environment in this project directory and install all the required packages there ? I think I should create this otherwise I am getting same error again and again. :(

Comment: Yes, you can. I have added the commands regarding to the virtual environment in the answer.

Comment: My problem was that, I was using pycharm commuinity IDE for the project. That is why I need to create a virtual environment manually. 
I run this command line to create virtual environment.

python -m venv F:\mypath\for\the\project

Then I activate this virtual environment by writing this command line in the terminal of pycharm.

F:\projectPath\venv\Scripts\activate.bat

it enabled venv . After that, I had to install all the requirements in the terminal that you suggested. Then I run flask db init it worked. :D